# ngtable filters not working

Tags: filter, ngtable

I am trying to implement [ngtable](http://esvit.github.io/ng-table/) in order to have out of the box filters and pagination but it seems not to be as easy to implement as they say.

My data is loading correctly in the table, however the actual filters are not responding at all. Below is my table code inside the MyCtrl:

```
  <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
      <tr ng-repeat="movie in items.movies">
            <td data-title="'Title'" filter="{ title: 'text'}" sortable="'title'">{{movie.title}}</td>
            <td data-title="'Duration'" filter="{duration: 'number'}" sortable="'duration'">{{movie.duration | durationFilter | date:'HH:mm:ss'}} hrs</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

In the app.js I serve data factory to the controller then trigger the ng table:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, itemsFactory){

 itemsFactory.getItems().success(function(data){
          $scope.items = data;
          tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, { data: data});
      });

 });
```

The result is that all the data is displayed and the input filters above the content, however, neither work. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your HTML contains something like `<table ng-table="tableParams"`, you want to assign your new `NgTableParams` to `$scope.tableParams` so the table can see them. Currently you are assigning a local variable.

Also, enable Javascript strict mode by "use strict". Avoids errors like that.

Answer (score -1):

try to change your code

```
<tr ng-repeat="movie in items.movies">
```

to

```
<tr ng-repeat="movie in $data">
```

Comment: Try this go to comments, not answers.  You are not sure this will solve the problem.